# DRYing html wrappers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I am using React js and am building a lot of repeating elements that are all getting wrapped in the same html, like so:

```
<div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
      <Element1 />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
      <Element2 />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
      <Element3 />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of having to constantly wrap every Element in 'child' and 'grand-child' divs, is there a simpler way I can write this so I don't have to repeat myself?

I've looked into something like the `innerHTML` property, which tags an html element and inserts information / elements inside of that original element. What I would like to do is the opposite and instead take my original element and wrap it with other html elements, but it seems like the `outerHTML` property does not operate in this manner.

Is there any way to wrap html elements as seen in this psuedo solution below? Thanks.

```
Let <foo></foo> =
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="parent">
  <foo>
    <p>This is the first element</p>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <p>This is the second element</p>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <p>This is the third element</p>
  </foo>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few good ways to do this: (1) using an array to store the contents and `.map`ping to the markup you want, and (2) creating a separate component to be the wrapper, passing along the contents as `children`. You could even combine these, depending on how reusable you want the wrapper component to be:

(1) This should produce the same markup you have in your first example, using `.map`:

```
<div>
  {[Element1, Element2, Element3].map((Element, index) => (
    <div class="child" key={index}>
      <div class="grand-child">
        <Element />
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

(2) If you want to break out to a separate component, you could do the following, using a stateless functional "Wrapper" component with `props.children` accessing the passed-down content:

```
const Wrapper = props => (
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
)

...

<div>
  <Wrapper>
    <Element1 />
  </Wrapper>
  <Wrapper>
    <Element2 />
  </Wrapper>
  <Wrapper>
    <Element3 />
  </Wrapper>
</div>
```

Finally, if you wanted to combine these, you can create a wrapper component and use it within a `.map` call to pass it different contents:

```
const Wrapper = props => (
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
)

...


<div>
  {[Element1, Element2, Element3].map((Element, index) => (
    <Wrapper key={index}>
      <Element />
    </Wrapper>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need [`children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx). So for you case I would suggest create wrapper Component.

```js
const ChildrenWrapper = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="child">
      <div className="grand-child">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And use it

```js
<div class="parent">
  <ChildWrapper>
    <p>This is the first element</p>
  </ChildWrapper>
  <ChildWrapper>
    <p>This is the second element</p>
  </ChildWrapper>
  <ChildWrapper>
    <p>This is the third element</p>
  </ChildWrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Anonymous down voter should speak up.